# Describing a transformation geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$: $R^3 \rightarrow R_3$ be the transformation $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right)= \begin{bmatrix} 13x-2y-3z \\ 10y-2x-6z \\ 5z-3x-6y \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $H$ be the plane $x+2y+3z=0$, let $N$ be the line $N=\text{Span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\right)$.

$(1)$ Find the standard matrix for $T$.

$(2)$ Show that the image (range) of $T$ is the plane $H$.

$(3)$ Show that $T(x)=14x$ for each vector $x$ on $H$.

$(4)$ Find all vectors $x$, for which $T(x)=0$.

$(5)$ Show that every vector $x$ can be described in an unique way as $x=n+h$, with $n$ in $N$, and $h$ $\hspace{0.6cm}$ in $H$.

$(6)$ Describe the transformation $T$ geometrically (use $5$ above).

**How do I describe the transformation $T$ geometrically?**

Comment: Think in terms of orthogonal projections. Note that with $P={1 \over 4}T$ we have $P=P^T$ and $P^2 = P$.

Comment: @copper.hat 
 
What is P? projection?

This is what we have covered in class so far:
Systems of Linear Equations
Row Reduction and Echelon Forms
Vector Equations
The Matrix Equation Ax = b
Solution Sets
Linear Independence
Linear Transformation
Matrix Operations
Inverse of a Matrix
Invertible Matrices

Comment: That should be 14 not 4 in my previous comment. Well, note that all vectors are mapped into the plane $H$. And note that $x-Tx$ is perpendicular to the plane. Finally, note the effect of of $T$ on vectors in $N$.

Comment: Oops again, I meant the effect of $T$ on vectors in $N^\circ$ the collection  of vectors orthogonal to $N$.

Answer (score 0):

If you first do the five preliminary questions, I expext the geometric description of $T$ will not be so hard anymore. You can find the standard matrix representation by plugging in the standard basis vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in $T$. The columns of the matrix are the images of these vectors. I think you'll get:

$T=\begin{pmatrix}
13&-2&-3\\
-2&10&-6\\
-3&-6&5
\end{pmatrix}$.

Furthermore, a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can always be written as the set of vectors orthogonal to a *normal vector* of that plane. Do you know a vector orthogonal to $H$? I'm sure questions (1) - (5) will help you answer (6).

Comment: I have done the previous questions (1-5). Yes, the vector N is orthogonal to the plane H.